# TeamCity unable to find the newman package after successful installation

Tags: teamcity

We run on dynamic testagent in teamcity so we don't have control over the teamcity.

My concern is **how install newman using npm and make it reflect to path?**

npm is already existing in teamcity so I tried to install newman using the cmd **npm install -g newman** Teamcity cmd installed newman successfully but when I tried to check the newman version.

Throws ERROR : newman unrecognized command.

I create a separate build step and tried to run the newman -version. No luck

I tried with absolute path "c:\etc\npm\newman.cmd" newman --version It worked.

but **newman run doesn't work with absolute path**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install newman to local

cmd - `npm install newman`

Run the below command.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;"./node_modules/.bin"
```